# Custom Python GUI Button + Link

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am learning the basics of python GUI and I came across button making. How would I link a file that I have done in photoshop to be the button? And when you click on it, it takes you to say, google?

This is what I have:

```
  from Tkinter import *


    root = Tk()

root.title("Simple GUI")
root.geometry("800x600")


app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
button1 = Button(app, text "Sample Button!")

button1.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [bitmap](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/bitmapimage.htm) image. Here's a link for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ImageTk, webbrowser

def launchGoogle():
    webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com')

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple GUI")
root.geometry("800x600")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="logo11w.png")
button1 = Button(app, text="Sample Button!", image=icon, command=launchGoogle)
button1.grid()

root.mainloop()
```